# Is the set $\Bbb Q$ a quotient set of $\Bbb Q^*$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, rational-numbers

Let $\Bbb Q^*=\{\frac a b: a\in \Bbb Z, b\in \Bbb N\}$.

From this definition we can see $c=\frac 2 3$ and $d=\frac 4 6$ are elements of $\Bbb Q^*$.

**Claim:**

$$\frac 2 3\neq \frac 4 6$$

**Proof:**

Suppose $a=b$. By the [definition of equality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Leibniz%27s_Law), $P(a)\iff P(b)$ for all properties.

Let $f:\Bbb Q^*\to  \Bbb Z/f \left (\frac \xi \psi \right )=\xi$.

We then have $f(c)=2\neq4=f(d)$ a contradiction. Thus $c\neq d._\square$

Now let's define the relation $$\simeq\subseteq \Bbb Q^*\times\Bbb Q^*: \left(\frac a b,\frac c d\right)\in \space \simeq\iff \text {ad=bc.}$$

Is the set we normally call the rational numbers, $\Bbb Q=\Bbb Q^*/\simeq$?

Comment: a/b is a NUMBER. A number e does not have a  single definable numerator  f(e)..... I think you are confused between the number a/b and the ordered pair (a,b).

Comment: Maybe I was unclear there, I editted the definition of my function. Before interpreting $\Bbb Q^*$ semantically, it is clear that the vertical concatenation of the symbols $a, /, b: \frac a b,$ where $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ are actually numbers, is an element $\Bbb Q^*$, and thus, $f$ is well-defined. Don't you agree?

Comment: You are using a non-standard notation.Aside from failing to exclude b=0, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. Which part of my question uses nonstandard notation?

Comment: Write $ 2/3 \neq 4/6$ on a scrap of paper and show it to somebody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exclude the case $b=0$. It's enough to let $a$ belong to $\mathbb {Z} $ and $b$ belong to $\mathbb{N}$. You can define the equivalence relation you need by $(a, b) \sim (c, d)$ if and only if $ad = bc $. Then yes, $\mathbb {Q}$ is the quotient of the big set by the equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of $\simeq$ the elements of $\mathbb Q^*$ are said to have a decimal expansion.

This reveals that these elements are supposed to be numbers (not some notation for pairs, or something else).

Consequently $f$ is not a well defined function.